# Lower triangular of matrix in eigen

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, eigen3, triangular

How to use [eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) library to compute lower triangular of input matrix without changing columns order?

for example for matrix:

```
A=[1 2 3;4 5 6 ;7 8 9]
```

I want the result to be:

```
1 0 0
4 0 0
7 0 0
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you mean by "without changing columns order"? I don't get what exactly you want to achieve, maybe you can add a minimal example!?

Answer (score 7):

Your text and your example don't match. I'll go through the three possible ways I understood your question. First, we'll set up the matrix:

```
Matrix3d mat;
mat << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;
```

If you wanted the actual lower triangular matrix, you would use:

```
std::cout << Matrix3d(mat.triangularView<Lower>()) << "\n\n";
```

or similar. The result is:

```
1 0 0
4 5 0
7 8 9
```

Note the 5,8,9 which are missing from your example. If you just wanted the left-most column, you would use:

```
std::cout << mat.col(0) << "\n\n";
```

which gives

```
1
4
7
```

If (as the second part of your example shows) you want `mat * [1, 0, 0]` then you could either do the matrix multiplication (not recommended) or just construct the result:

```
Matrix3d z = Matrix3d::Zero();
z.col(0) = mat.col(0);

std::cout << z << "\n\n";
```

which gives the same result as your example:

```
1 0 0
4 0 0
7 0 0
```